# Why can't I get the size of a List that is the value of a Map key

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-binding

I receive this error:

**Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text**

when I try to access the size of a List like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!accountsMap[key].size}" />
```

with a Map declared in the controller like this:

```
public Map<Id, Account[]> accountsMap {get; set;}
```

Does this just not work or am I missing something?

Comment: What's your variable name? In VF you access `map` but in Apex you've shown us `accountsMap`... If the key is of type Id VF shouldn't try to think about it as a number field...

Comment: Is that a typo in the question? you said "the size of a List", but your code has a Map, not a List

Comment: Sorry; forgot to change _map_ to _accountsMap_ in the markup.

Comment: @Sem0 the value for the matching key is a List.

Comment: This is a dupe based on the link @mast0r submitted. It's just not possible to do it in a VisualForce page.